# Post JSON with @ManyToOne Relationship in Spring Boot

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I have written a test application in spring boot. Employees have a relation to a department. CRUD works, but I'm not sure I'm doing it the correct way.

When I will create a new employee I have to send the following post request

```
    "id": 3,
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "salary": 50000,
    "department": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Sales"
    } 
}
```

This is the employee class:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Department department;
    private int salary;
```

This is the create method in the EmployeeController:

```
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee create(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeService.add(employee);
    }
```

The department entries already exists.
Is it possible to create an employee without filling the complete relation
(department)?
I would like to add the department id only. But if I do this, the name field in the json data is empty (get request)

```
id  3
firstname   "John"
lastname    "Doe"
department  
  id    2
  name  null
salary  50000
```

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You are taking an Entity as a request body which is not the correct approach. You can take Some VO as Request Object and then convert to Entity inside a service.
For E.g

```
EmployeeVO{
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
List<Integer> departments;
}
```

Also, you can use Jackson annotations like 
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) to ignore unknown attributes and include not null attributes.